# Application not found if clicking empty DVD disk icon

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hardware-failure, dvd, cd-drive

Should Windows 8.1 display window to place files if double-clicking CD disk icon?

My box does not. It shows absurd "Application not found" message.

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: This appears to be an indication of severe system integrity issues.

Comment: Were you using some 3rd party DVD software which you later uninstalled? @Ramhound - maybe not so severe issues, perhaps only a crappy 3rd party software uninstaller, which doesn't do proper cleanup of all links to its DVD-related handlers. So Windows gets information that the uninstalled software is still there.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely looks as remnants of some 3rd party software you recently uninstalled, but it had **poor-quality uninstaller, not removing all links to software**.

You have these options:

- try perform registry cleanup so leftover link to your recent software is removed
- try return the software you uninstalled or some other DVD-handling software so they will properly renew DVD-handler link to their application.
- try searching resources how to fix the problem manually. This can be most lenghty and dangerous, but can help.

General advice: do not use your computer just for *trying* random 3rd party applications. They often uninstall badly. Test them in virtual machine instead.

Comment: Please let me know after you find something :)